# Distributing integers over a range so they come to a total

Tags: excel

I need to distribute a number of hours spent travelling across a number of clients in a form but the hours against each client has to be an integer.  Obviously some of the clients will be zero hours and others may be 1 or two.  I don't mind who gets what but the allocation should be as equitable as possible.

For example I have 9 hours distributed over 6 people or 5 hours distributed over 3 people.  My list has up to 40 people and typically I have to allocate 10 to 12 hours.

Would rather not use a random function as I don't want the results to be constantly changing.  Would prefer just to use Excel spreadsheet functions not VBA.

Help would be appreciated

Roger

Comment: So if you distribute 9 hours over six people, then three of them will get 2 hours, while the other three get one hour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enter the total hours in **A1** and  the total people in **A2** and then in **B1** enter:

```
= ROUND(ROW()/$A$2*$A$1,0)
```

and in **B2** enter:

```
= IF(ROW()<=$A$2,ROUND(ROW()/$A$2*$A$1,0)-SUM(B$1:B1),"")
```

and copy down.  For example:

[image]

Comment: Superb, can't believe it could be done with such a simple formulae.  Very clever using the row number to control the divisor.  Thanks